# what is difference between round brackets() and curly braces {} in terms of creating background processes in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, background-process

I tried the following using `( )&` but it doesn't assign my IP addresses and it looks like `wait` statement doesn't wait. Same code works without `( )&`. What could be some other possible way to execute this `( )&` block of code in parallel? What will happen if I use curly braces instead?

To make it simple

iface[i] are eth0,eth1,eth2,eth3 and so on

nic_count are number of eth port.

initially all ip_addr[i]=0 are assigned.

```
i=0 
while ((i < Snic_count )); do
    if [[ ${#ip_addr[$i]} == 0 ]]; then
    (
           dhclient ${iface[$i]};
           sleep 10
           ip_addr[$i]=`ip 4 -a show ${iface[$i]} | awk '/inet/ {gsub("/..$","",$2); print $2}'`
           if [[ ${#ip_addr[$i]} == 0 ]]; then
                 echo -e "Unable to assign an IP address for ${iface[$i]}"
           fi
     )&    
    fi
    1+=1
done 
wait
```

Comment: We don't know where `nic_count` or `iface` are supposed to come from; there's no mention where `( )&` is supposed to be in use. Impossible to answer ...

Comment: We also don't know what `$nic_count`, `$ip_addr`, `$iface`, etc. are so this code is not runnable. Is this really the simplest example? Please read about [mre] and then [edit] to provide a _minimal_ example.

Comment: See [Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) in the manual for the difference between `( )` and `{ }`.

Comment: once you background a block of code it becomes a brand new (OS-level) process and loses any association (memory wise) with the parent; in this case the *ip assignment* (`ip_addr[$i]=...`) is performed in the child process while the parent process is oblivious to any variable assignments (made in the child process); to pass info between different OS processes you need to look at various methods of interprocess communications (eg, files, sockets, shared memory, queuing system, a database, etc) ....

Comment: Also you have a typo `1+=1` that means the loop never exits if the initial condition is true, you need `(( i+=1 ))`.

Comment: imo the 'easiest' to implement would be files, preferably a separate file for each backgrounded process to eliminate the need for locking (to keep multiple pids from overwriting/scrambling data); have the parent create the file names and make sure each child is told which file to write to; after all child processes have completed the parent  then reads results from the collection of files

Comment: how about declaring the ip_addr array a global variable?

Comment: *`What will happen if I use curly braces instead?`* ... try it out and see what happens.

Comment: Variables are global by default. The problem is that since you're using a subshell via `( )` then (quoting from the manual): `Since the list is executed in a subshell, **variable assignments do not remain in effect after the subshell completes**.` You'd need to switch to braces to avoid the subshell and allow variable assignments to persist.

Comment: doesn't matter if the variable is 'local' or 'global' ... it's only local/global to the current (OS-level) process; a 'global' variable is not shareable between separate (OS-level) processes

Comment: Actually even braces won't help if you're also backgrounding with `&` - that also creates a new subshell. You really need interprocess communication if you want to run things in parallel and keep a synchronized variable state.

Comment: whether you use parens or braces won't matter re: *`ip assignment`* since your plan is to spawn multiple, separate (OS-level) processes in parallel; once a process is backgrounded (ie, a new OS-level process is spawned), regardless of whether you use parens or braces, you 'break' the ability to share memory (eg, variable assignments) between different parts of your code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK so I finally figure it out. New child process's data is destroyed as soon as they return to parent.
So solution to that is I write each of the ip address to an external file like...(**`echo ip_addr[$i] > ip_num$i`**)
Anyways if anyone can come up with an idea to avoid too many file creations would be appreciated.

```
while ((i < Snic_count )); do
    if [[ ${#ip_addr[$i]} == 0 ]]; then
    (
           dhclient ${iface[$i]};
           sleep 10
           ip_addr[$i]=`ip 4 -a show ${iface[$i]} | awk '/inet/ {gsub("/..$","",$2); print $2}'`
           if [[ ${#ip_addr[$i]} == 0 ]]; then
                 echo -e "Unable to assign an IP address for ${iface[$i]}"
           fi
           #save each output ip to a separate file.
           echo ip_addr[$i] > ip_num$i
     )&    
    fi
    1+=1
done 
wait
```